# Putting Some Part in Double Quotes in R

Tags: r, string, double-quotes, single-quotes

I want to put some part of object into double quote like the example given below:

**Required Output**

```
"Group 1" = 3, "Group 2" = 3
```

**MWE**

```
Test <- structure("Group 1 = 3, Group 2 = 3", class = "noquote")
Test
[1] Group 1 = 3, Group 2 = 3
as.character(Test)
[1] "Group 1 = 3, Group 2 = 3"
```

**Edited**

Actually I have a long character string (here Labs)

```
Labs  <- c("Group 1", "Group 2")

Test <- noquote(paste(Labs, "= 3", collapse = ", "))
Test
[1] Group 1 = 3, Group 2 = 3
```

However, I want to have output like this

```
"Group 1" = 3, "Group 2" = 3
```

Comment: `Test <- c('"Group 1" = 3', '"Group 2" = 3')`

Comment: Thanks @d.b for your comment. Your given code gives `c("Group 1 = 3", " Group 2 = 3")` but the required output should be `c("Group 1" = 3, " Group 2" = 3)`.

Comment: `help(Quotes)` explains all this and more... It says "Single quotes are normally only used to delimit character constants containing double quotes. "

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use single quotes to let R know where the string begins and ends. That will let you have double quotes inside of it:

```
Test <- c('"Group 1" = 3', '"Group 2" = 3')
```

If you `print` it, then by default it's going to show you the escape characters. However, you can just `cat` it, or use some fancier options, depending on your needs.

```
cat(Test)
```

> ```
> "Group 1" = 3 "Group 2" = 3
> ```

Comment: Thanks @Hack-R for your answer. I would appreciate if you have a look on my updates. Thanks

Comment: using `cat(Test, sep = ", ")` generates your desired output.